# Matrix Calculus Reference Request

Tags: matrices, reference-request, matrix-calculus

Looking for a good book on matrix calculus. I have seen the matrix cook book but it is mostly identities/equations without any proofs or work. I want a thorough treatment of the topic.

Comment: This might be useful: [The matrix calculus you need for deep learning]
 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01528)

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

[This MIT short course on matrix calculus](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-s096-matrix-calculus-for-machine-learning-and-beyond-january-iap-2023/) may be helpful.